# Modern CMake (3.8+) - FindCUDA deprecated, what about non .cu files?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, deprecated

I have a C++/CUDA project based on CMake. Currently I'm using CMake 3.11 and CUDA 9.0 and I'm reading that now CUDA is a first-class language in CMake, so I can simply add `.cu` files and it will automatically call the NVCC compiler to take care of them. Before this, we had to use `find_package(CUDA)` and so on, but now this is a **deprecated feature**.

Now the question: how do we compile normal `.cpp` files that still make use of the CUDA host libraries? `cudaMalloc`, `cudaFree`, etc. My solution so far is to `set_source_files_properties(file.cpp PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)` but I don't feel this is the right thing to do. Since this file doesn't contain device code, it should be compiled with the GCC compiler including and linking to the CUDA libraries.

Another issue with this approach is that it propagates very quickly to the rest of the project. Say a header file that defines a struct containing a `dims3` variable, then every `.cpp` file that `#include`s this header will need to be considered as a CUDA file.

Answer (score 1):

> how do we compile normal .cpp files that still make use of the CUDA host libraries?

With your regular C++ compiler. There is no need to treat them as `LANGUAGE CUDA`.

I recently made the switch to CMake's native CUDA support in [this repository](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) of mine. I now have:

```
add_executable(device_management 
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL examples/by_runtime_api_module/device_management.cpp)
add_executable(execution_control 
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL examples/by_runtime_api_module/execution_control.cu)
```

Both of these use the runtime API (actually, they use my C++'ified wrappers, which use the runtime API - but most of the wrappers is header-only), but the second one has a kernel in it, so I made it a `.cu` and it gets compiled by CUDA. The `.cpp` builds and runs fine by plain old GCC.

Comment: My question was more about how to find the `include_directories`, `link_directories` and libraries without `find_package(CUDA)`. But I can see that you use `CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. Where does this come from, is it part of standard CMake as well? And what's the purpose of `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`? Thanks!

Comment: @user1011113: So, I don't actually have a good answer to that aspect of your question! I thought I did, but apparently some of my users come up against this problem and there doesn't seem to be a straightforward solution (that I know of). Sorry! ... if you've solved this yourself, please post another answer.